# Processing substitute long variables for something shorter

Tags: processing

I am wondering if there is any way to replace something such as `entities.entities[playerData].` with something like `enti.` for while the code still recognizes it all the same.

I've looked it up, and I didn't find any answer on the internet. I assume it's just because I don't know how to word the question correctly.